# PayPal IPN sends 2 notifications to my PHP IPN Listener

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I have this IPN listener for PayPal, everything is fine, but PayPal is sending me 2 notifications with the same transaction id. 
How to make it send only 1 notification?

This script file works without any problems, once the user buys something I get the notification and I process it, but after that a second notification is sent to me and this is annoying me. Why does PayPal keep sending me another notification?

```
<?
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                $req .= "&$key=$value";
            }

            $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
            //$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

            //$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

            $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);



            $bussines = addslashes($_POST['bussines']);
            $receiver_email = addslashes( $_POST['receiver_email']);
            $txn_type = addslashes($_POST['txn_type']);

            $mc_gross = addslashes($_POST['mc_gross']);
            $tax = doubleval(addslashes($_POST['tax']));
            $payment_status = addslashes($_POST['payment_status']);
            $item_number = addslashes($_POST['item_number']);
            $item_name = addslashes($_POST['item_name']);
            $transaction_id = addslashes($_POST['txn_id']);
            $currency = addslashes($_POST['mc_currency']);
            $payer_email = addslashes($_POST['payer_email']);
            $username = addslashes($_POST['custom']);


if (!$fp) {
                write_log($log_dir,'Unable to fsockopen ssl://www.paypal.com'); 
            } else {
                fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
                while (!feof($fp)) {
                    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
                    if(strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                        write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Status: VERIFIED]');
                        if(strtolower($receiver_email) == strtolower($mucore['paypal']['email'])){
                            if(($txn_type == 'web_accept' OR $txn_type == 'subscr_payment') AND $payment_status == 'Completed'){
                                write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Payment Status: Completed]');
                                if($tax > 0){$mc_gross -=$tax;}

                                if(is_file('*****/'.$transaction_id.'.txt')){
                                    write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Error Message: Transaction ID Already Processed]');
                                }else{
                                    if($item_number == md5('USD'.intval($mc_gross).$username.$mucore['cryptkey'])){
                                        write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Success Message: Accepted MD5 String]');


                                        //HERE I PROCESS THE TRANSCATION



                                        }else{
                                            write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Error Message: Account ID not found in MEMB_INFO]');
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Error Message: Invalid MD5 String] [Amount: '.$mc_gross.' '.$currency.' / Tax: '.$tax.']');
                                    }
                                }
                            }elseif($payment_status == 'Reversed' OR $payment_status == 'Refunded'){
                                write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Payment Status: Refunded or Reversed]'); 
                            }else{
                                write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Payment Status: '.$payment_status.']');
                            }
                        }else{
                            write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Error Message: Invalid Paypal Receiver Email]');
                        }
                    }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                        write_log($log_dir,'[Account ID: '.$username.'] [Item Number: '.$item_number.'] [Item Name: '.$item_name.'] [Transaction ID: '.$transaction_id.'] [Status: INVALID]');
                    }
                }
                fclose ($fp);
            }

?>
```

Comment: "How to make it send only 1 notification?" you don't, you check if its already been notified and ignore any additional ones. this can happen if your IPN script is returning the wrong headers or just the 'nature' of the internet

Comment: Oki thanks for answer, i tough it was wrong like that.